# Spring Boot multiple request types for same endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently porting an old API to Spring Boot and have encountered a problem. In the old API, two types of cURL requests could be made to the same endpoint: one for posting JSON data, and the other for posting JSON data with a file. The two requests look like such:

JSON Only:

```
curl -i -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/myEndpoint' \
-H 'Accept:application/json' \
-H 'someheader:value' \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-d '{ "jsondata":"goesHere" }'
```

JSON with image:

```
curl -i -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/myEndpoint' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed' \
-H 'someheader:value' \ 
-F '{ "jsondata":"goesHere" }' \
-F "file=@filewanted.file"
```

As can been seen, I can either send a Request Body or a Multipart/Mixed request to the same endpoint, and depending on what is received, the server will execute some business logic.

I have tried to replicate this behavior is spring to little avail. I am able to replicate the JSON only request with ease:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity createActivityFile(@RequestHeader(value = "someheader") String someheader,
                                         @RequestBody() String body,) {
    // do something...
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The trouble arises when I add a multipart file to the mix. I've tried:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity createActivityFile(@RequestHeader(value = "someheader") String someheader,
                                         @RequestBody() String body,
                                         @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    // do something...
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But with this, I always get a `The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found` error.

This leads me to ask, is what I am attempting to do possible with Spring Boot? If so, what would my `RequestMapping` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `@Consumes` annotation

consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

And other endpoint with different `MediaType`

Comment: Just to clarify, I am using the same endpoint (`/myEndpoint`) and I will have two functions mapped to this endpoint, with the difference being their consumed `MediaType`?

Comment: I just tried it out and it works! However, your answer isn't suited for Spring Boot, which doesn't have `@Consumes`. Instead you add `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to the `@RequestMapping`. If you update your answer, I'd be happy to accept it.